# How to fix the Invalid OAuth 2.0 Access Token AccountKit error?

Tags: android, account-kit

My android app was removed, the error was Invalid OAuth 2.0 Access Token using AccountKit. 
Google gave me this message:

[picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KjSb.png)

Then, they give me this message:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid OAuth 2.0 Access Token",
      "type": "EMApiException",
      "code": 190,
      "error_data": [

      ],
      "fbtrace_id": "A-1MTjuDl-NerwvCnecjtZJ"
   }
}
```

I dont know what to do, please help!